# How to make Selection.AutoFilter starts in row 3 instead of row 1

Tags: excel, autofilter, vba

I have this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Set wbks = Workbooks.Open("\\MyPath\Workbook.xlsx")
        wbks.Sheets("Control").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        Selection.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Target.Value '7 is the filter # column
    End If
End Sub
```

It works well only if headers in the sheet `control` are located in row 1.
My problem is that `\\MyPath\Workbook.xlsx` is a *read only* file and its headers starts in row 3.

Comment: @phalanx Please close the question by marking the correct answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try below code :

- Avoid using Select in your code.
- Always set `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` at bottom when you turn off the screen updating at beignning of procedure.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Target.Value <> "" Then
        Set wbks = Workbooks.Open("\\MyPath\Workbook.xlsx")
        wbks.Sheets("Control").Activate
        wbks.Sheets("Control").Range("A3:G3").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Target.Value    '7 is the filter # column
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it was pretty useful

Answer (score 1):

Try addding this code before the autofilter

```
Rows("3:3").Select
```

Making the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Excel.Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Target.Value <> "" Then
            Set wbks = Workbooks.Open("\\MyPath\Workbook.xlsx")
        wbks.Sheets("Control").Activate
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
        Rows("3:3").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        Selection.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Target.Value '7 is the filter # column
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope it helps,
Bruno

Comment: Sheets("Formular").Select
Range("A1:F1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter... I am trying to use this filter and when I use this command (there is no data in first row, but data is there in the below rows), There is an error mentioning you can't apply the auto filter using this range.